# Problems with User Function in Python 3 Not Defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that organizes baseball player stats and info.  I am required to use an input file which contains all the data to be organized including player name, team, hit record etc.

I am having an issue with one of the functions I defined, and I am not really sure where to go from here.  Every time I run the program I keep getting an error in Lines 73, 25, 53, 49 - all relating to the `name "processFile" is not defined`.  I am not sure if I am supposed to define that outside the function as a variable?

I am posting the code I have so far, and the data file I am organizing.  Thank you!

```
print("Welcome to The Baseball Database!")

def terminate():
    """This function quits the program"""
    userExit = input("Are you sure you want to quit? Yes or No?: ")
    userExit = userExit.lower()
    if userExit == "yes":
        print("The Baseball Database is terminating gracefully.")
        exit()
    if userExit == "no":
        introRerun()
    else:
        print("Please enter 'Yes' or 'No'.")
        terminate()

def assist():
    """This function offers help to the user"""
    print("The Baseball Database supports the following command functions:")
    print("INPUT - which allows you to input a file path")
    print("TEAM - which allows you to identify a team, and provide info about the players")
    print("REPORT - which reports the number of hits")
    print("HELP - for assistance")
    print("QUIT - to exit the database")
    print("Please choose from one of the above functions.")
    introRerun()


def filePath():
    """This function allows the user to input a file"""
    file = input("Please enter the file path to read: ")
    fileObject = open(file) 
    return fileObject


def introRerun():
    """This function reprompts the user to enter a command"""
    introLoop = input("Please enter a command, or type 'Help' for a list of options: ")
    introLoop = introLoop.lower()
    if introLoop == "quit":
        terminate()

    if introLoop == "help":
        assist()

    if introLoop == "input":
        filePath()

    if introLoop == "team":
        processFlie(fileObject)

    else:
        print("Please enter a valid command, for a list of options type 'Help'")
        introRerun()


def processFile(inputFilePath):
    """This function processes the input file"""
    myList = None
    fileHandle = open(inputFilePath, "r")
    for line in fileHandle:
        tokens = line.split(sep = ";")
        entry = {"Name" : tokens [0], "Team" : tokens [1], "Games Played" : tokens [2], "At Bats" : tokens [3], "Runs Scored" : tokens [4], "Hits" : tokens [5], "Doubles" : tokens [6], "Triples" : tokens [7], "Homeruns" : tokens [8]}
        myList.append(entry)
    return myList


playerList = None
#playerList = processFile(filePath)
intro = input("Please enter a command, or type 'Help' for a list of options: ")
intro = intro.lower()

if intro == "help":
    assist()
if intro == "input":
    filePath()
    introRerun()
if intro == "team":
    if playerList != None:
        print("Error! You must first INPUT a file to be read!")
        filePath()
    else:
        filePath()
if intro == "no" or intro == "quit":
    terminate()
```

Input:

```
De Aza, Alejandro; CWS; 153; 607; 84; 160; 27; 4; 17
Hunter, Torii; DET; 144; 606; 90; 184; 37; 5; 17
Hamilton, Josh; LAA; 151; 576; 73; 144; 32; 5; 21
Choo, Shin-Soo; CIN; 154; 569; 107; 162; 34; 2; 21
Upton, Justin; ATL; 149; 558; 94; 147; 27; 2; 27
Cabrera, Miguel; DET; 148; 555; 103; 193; 26; 1; 44
Posey, Buster; SF; 148; 520; 61; 153; 34; 1; 15
Suzuki, Ichiro; NYY; 150; 520; 57; 136; 15; 3; 7
Holliday, Matt; STL; 141; 520; 103; 156; 31; 1; 22
Headley, Chase; SD; 141; 520; 59; 130; 35; 2; 13
Cabrera, Asdrubal; CLE; 136; 508; 66; 123; 35; 2; 14
Pierzynski, A.J.; TEX; 134; 503; 48; 137; 24; 1; 17
Hoes, L.J.; HOU; 46; 167; 24; 48; 7; 2; 1
Young Jr., Eric; COL; 57; 165; 22; 40; 9; 3; 1
Hairston, Scott; CHC; 52; 99; 13; 17; 2; 0; 8
d'Arnaud, Travis; NYM; 31; 99; 4; 20; 3; 0; 1
Ankiel, Rick; NYM; 20; 66; 7; 12; 4; 1; 2
Ankiel, Rick; HOU; 25; 62; 6; 12; 3; 0; 5
den Dekker, Matt; NYM; 27; 58; 7; 12; 1; 0; 1
Sanchez, Angel; CWS; 1; 2; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0
```

Comment: Read the error message more carefully: you have a typo inside `introRerun` - it is calling `processFlie` not `processFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `processFile`, but use `processFlie` with inversion of `i` and `l` ... Just a typo for the error.

But there are numerous other problems in your code :

- you have a command *loop* but process it only once
- you need the name of the file throughout the program but do not keep it anywhere
- you try to open ... the result of a previous open !
- you never close the file if you open it
- you initialize `myList` to `None` before calling `append` on it (should be : `myList = []`)

Good luck, when all that is fixed, it will run :-)

Comment: Just changed that - swear I checked and checked for typos.  Its still throwing an error though.  Now fileObject is not defined. Thank you guys for that though.

Comment: @flamingjune5dwj that's because fileObject is declared in another scope

Comment: @TimCastelijns if I were to create a global variable   fileObject = filePath()  would that correctly define it?

Comment: @flamingjune5dwj You must make a choice between passing variable to function or using globals. In fact the better design whould be to use a class and having the file name as an attribute. But with your current design you need to declare the file name as global - but see also my edit above ..

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you for the help!  I am working on the things you mentioned now, and hopefully I will get it all ironed out :)  I think one of the issues is I am not sure exactly how to get the returned file from the INPUT function to become the global variable that I can then pass to the next function.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Also, sorry for the neophyte questions - I am just learning how to program in the last few weeks. >.<

Comment: @flamingjune5dwj : as you are a beginner, Python documentation and google are your friends. To use a global variable declare it before the functions that use it and in each function that uses it declare `global filename` before using it

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, you are right - thank god for google eh… the issue is I think am still trying to figure out what questions to exactly ask and how to ask them.  I really appreciate all of your help.  I will work on the things you suggested :)